# Setting up Dynamics AX 2009 team development environment using TFS

Tags: tfs, installation, dynamics-ax-2009

For about a week now I try to set up a Dynamics AX 2009 team development environment, and keep hitting roadblock after roadblock (mostly about setting up TFS).

Are there any **working** installation instructions for using Dynamics AX Team Server with Team Foundation Server 2008? 
Has anyone ever got this combination (AX TS & TFS) up and running?

The official installation documents are riddled with errors (saying /Sites instead of /Websites) which makes using them a real PitA! The MS certification MB6-820 and it's learning material does say nothing about distributed programming, only about single user installations.

How do others install a distributed AX dev system? Ship the servers to MS so they will handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARG! The problem seems simple:

**Never ever install AX Team Server on a non-english version of Windows Server!**

Some weird translators have translated the name of computer accounts. For example the system account "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" is called "NT-AUTORITÄT\NETZWERKDIENST" in the german version of Windows Server.

Now a lot of programs have the name of the account hardcoded, therefore fail to find the account they are looking for, since the name does not match.

Point of the story: always install AX 2009 team server on an english version of Windows Server.